# Semaphores for fortran

Tags: fortran, semaphore, shared-memory

Can anyone help with writing a semaphore function in fortran? I have multiple processes running and I have to synchronize them using semaphore. Such a code could be found for C++ etc., but I could not find any such code for fortran.

If I could call C/C++ function from fortran code, that would also suffice, since C++ semaphore function is already there.

PS: (Additional Explanation) Here is the code which works for C++. I have some fortran applications (as part of standard benchmark) but no semaphore code to synchronize them.

```
  int get_semaphore ()
  {
   int sem_id;
   sem_id = semget(SEM_ID, 1, IPC_CREAT | 0666);
if (sem_id == -1) {
    perror("get_semaphore: semget");
    exit(1);
}
return sem_id;
}


int set_semaphore (int sem_id, int val)
  { 
   return semctl(sem_id, 0, SETVAL, val);
  }

void decrement_semaphore (int sem_id)
{
 struct sembuf sem_op;
 sem_op.sem_num = 0;
 sem_op.sem_op = -1;
sem_op.sem_flg = 0;
semop(sem_id, &sem_op, 1);
 }

 void wait_semaphore (int sem_id)
{   
 struct sembuf sem_op;
sem_op.sem_num = 0;
sem_op.sem_op = 0;
sem_op.sem_flg = 0;
  semop(sem_id, &sem_op, 1);
  }
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I would suggest being more specific in your question what do you want to accomplish. Did you try anything already? Can you post a code sample? You may want to look into MPI for Fortran: http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/

Comment: @IRO-bot I have given a c++ code fragment. I can't use MPI, since it is not a parallel code: just for synchronization, semaphore is needed. Other than that, there is not sharing.

Comment: OK, hopefully someone will chip in, this is not really my domain :)

Comment: I still don't understand.  How are you doing the multithreading in fortran that you need semaphores?   There is no native Fortran way of accessing such low-level system stuff.

Comment: @JonathanDursi I am doing multi-core simulation using Marss and each core runs one benchmark program which are fortran or C program. To make a checkpoint at the region of interest of a benchmark, I want to use semaphore. For benchmarks in C, I already have the code. Just for fortran, I need one. Fortran-C mixed programming could work, if I could call C function from fortran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenMP provides semaphores under the term "lock".   Normally these aren't used since OpenMP provides higher level tasking constructs, but if you want to do it yourself, that could be a way to do explicit locking/unlocking with Fortran.

P.S.  If you want to do it from Fortran by calling the C code that you already have, that could by done by using the ISO C Binding of Fortran 2003.   There are many questions/answers here about how this works.   I drafted declarations for your Fortran program to match the C routines.  These tell the Fortran compiler how to call the C routines using the calling conventions of the C compiler.   These are untested and may need debugging:

```
use iso_c_binding

interface semaphore_stuff

   function get_semaphore () bind (C, name="get_sempaphore")
      import
      integer (c_int) :: get_semaphore
   end function get_semaphore ()

   function set_semaphore (sem_id, int val) bind (C, name="get_sempaphore")
      import
      integer (c_int) :: set_semaphore
      integer (c_int), intent (in), value :: sem_id
      integer (c_int), intent (in) value :: val
   end function set_semaphore

   subroutine decrement_semaphore (sem_id) bind (C, name="decrement_semaphore")
      import
      integer (c_int), intent (in), value :: sem_id
   end subroutine decrement_semaphore

   subroutine wait_semaphore (sem_id) bind (C, name="wait_semaphore")
      import
      integer (c_int), intent (in), value :: sem_id
   end subroutine wait_semaphore

end interface semaphore_stuff
```

Comment: It's not clear to me how the user would use that with their MPMD setup though; how do you get the different programs to agree on the semaphore?  I guess mmap some shard memory segment and have a lock there?  But that just shifts the problem to how you use mmap with fortran...